# Alternative to Design Manager

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, design-manager

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2013 and i'm looking for an alternative to Design Manager, which is not included into foundation. Since i don't have the HTML version of the master.page and i'm a bit new to sharepoint it would be quite diffucult to do it without an alternative to Design Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sharepoint Designer. Copy one of the existing Sharepoint masterpages to start from. Connect to site using SP Designer **or** Map network drive to site and edit files in your favorite IDE.

More on SP F Branding here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/82d56cc6-a15f-4dfd-b190-eb074393893a/sharepoint-2013-foundation-editing-master-pages?forum=sharepointgeneral

and here: 
[branding sharepoint foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87545/branding-sharepoint-foundation-2013)